# Move points from user to another using transactions realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using firebase real time database i want to move points from user to another but to keep conflicts away ( may user get coins from multi other users at the same time ) i have to use transactions.

My data structure :

```
{  
      uid-1:
             {
                points: 30
             },
        uid-2:
           {
              points:60
            }
}
```

So i need two transactions one substracts uid-1 and second increases uid-2

But I'm afraid of that if one transaction success and other one fails .. any sol to revert the operation or update both same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no secure way to implement conditionality between multiple transactions.

If both operations depend on each other they should be run as a single transaction. That means you have an optimistic lock on the entire "users", but in your current data structure and solution that is required.

An alternative is to not update the balance, but just keep a list of transactions. In that case you can ensure both the addition for the first user and subtraction for the second user are written atomically by using a multi-location update. In JavaScript this would look something like:

```
ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
var updates = {};
let transactionID = ref.push().key;
updates["uid1/transactions/"+transactionID] =  20;
updates["uid2/transactions/"+transactionID] = -20;
ref.update(updates);
```

The above write operation will either succeed completely, or fail completely. This ensures your database is always correct.

Comment: but if i use the alternative way,, how to ensure total points doesn't go -ve ? @Frank-van-puffelen

Comment: Sorry, but what is `-v`?

Comment: Sorry , i meant negative

Comment: That won't be possible with this approach, unless you have a "transaction processor" task somewhere in a trusted environment. Or of course run the both updates in a single transaction, as I gave as the first option. Please keep the scope of your question fixed, as you initial question doesn't mention preventing a negative balance.

Comment: Sorry for breaking the scope of question but what you mean with transaction processor?

Comment: That'd be a trusted process that can be trusted to handle these transactions reliable, typically by processing only one at a time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189363/discussion-between-saifallak-and-frank-van-puffelen).